# Iterate from col/row in matrix python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, scipy

I'm trying to take a column from sparse matrix(with scipy sparse library), and use for other operation in Python 3.
I tried to do this:

```
for l in range (0,10):


    vec[l] =np.squeeze(np.asarray(sparse_matrix[:,l].A))
    print(l,vec[l])
```

working but take often the same output, because l can't iterate in the range. 
so my output is the same :

```
1 [4,5,4,5]
2 [4,5,4,5]
...
...
```

where was I wrong?
i m not sure if i do this `np.squeeze(np.asarray(sparse_matrix[:,x].A))` where x is a number, I take an array from my columns of sparse matrix, I saw it in another StackOverflow question and seems work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried more time, and i fixed with this

```
vec[l]=sparse_matrix.getcol(l).toarray()
```

in this way, at each iteration change the value of l.